# Ansible loops and template... again

Tags: ansible

I am trying setup a playbook to generalise the setup of logfile centralisation and templates.
I want to write rsyslog.d/ config files using ansible vars through a generic template.

**The vars :**

```
  vars:
    loglist:
      - app_id: 'dsm'
        rsyslog_conf_file: '13-dsm.conf'
        ruleset: 'Centralize'
        logfiles:
          - name: /var/opt/ds_agent/diag/amEvent.log
            regex: 'zzz'
          - name: /XXXX/amEvent.log
            regex: 'xxx'
      - app_id: 'audit'
        rsyslog_conf_file: '06-auditd.conf'
        ruleset: 'Centralize'
        logfiles:
          - name: /var/log/audit/audit.log
            regex: ''
```

**the task :**

```
  - name: Rsyslog logs config
    template:
      src: ./templates/rsyslog.d/99-generic-template.conf.j2
      dest: /tmp/{{ item.0.rsyslog_conf_file }}
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: '0644'
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ loglist }}"
      - logfiles
```

**the template :**

```
{% for val in loglist | subelements('logfiles') %}

input(type="imfile"
    File="{{ val.1.name }}"
    Tag="{{ val.0.app_id }}__"
{% if val.1.regex|length %}
    startmsg.regex="{{ val.1.regex }}"
{% endif %}
    Ruleset="{{ val.0.ruleset }}"
    addMetadata="on")

{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting close, but the template is going through the entire list, iterating all logfilename each time, instead of going through the current item only.

**The result** is 2 files with the same content :
13-dsm.conf and 06-auditd.conf :

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/opt/ds_agent/diag/amEvent.log"
    Tag="dsm__"
    startmsg.regex="a"
    Ruleset="Centralizehorsprod"
    addMetadata="on")


input(type="imfile"
    File="/XXXX/amEvent.log"
    Tag="dsm__"
    startmsg.regex="X"
    Ruleset="Centralizehorsprod"
    addMetadata="on")


input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/log/audit/audit.log"
    Tag="audit__"
    startmsg.regex="hqhq"
    Ruleset="Centralizehorsprod"
    addMetadata="on")
```

**Expected result** is 2 files with their respective logfilename.

06-audit.conf

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/log/audit/audit.log"
    Tag="audit__"
    startmsg.regex="hqhq"
    Ruleset="Centralizehorsprod"
    addMetadata="on")
```

and 13-dsm.conf

```
input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/opt/ds_agent/diag/amEvent.log"
    Tag="dsm__"
    startmsg.regex="a"
    Ruleset="Centralizehorsprod"
    addMetadata="on")


input(type="imfile"
    File="/XXXX/amEvent.log"
    Tag="dsm__"
    startmsg.regex="X"
    Ruleset="Centralizehorsprod"
    addMetadata="on")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**task**

```
  - name: Rsyslog logs config
    template:
      src: ./templates/99-generic-template.conf.j2
      dest: /tmp/{{ item.rsyslog_conf_file }}
    with_items:
    - "{{ loglist }}"
```

**template**

```
{% for val in item.logfiles %}
input(type="imfile"
    File="{{ val.name }}"
    Tag="{{ item.app_id }}__"
{% if val.regex|length %}
    startmsg.regex="{{ val.regex }}"
{% endif %}
    Ruleset="{{ item.ruleset }}"
    addMetadata="on")
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hell yea ! Much simpler than I thought...

Comment: yes , it's not that hard ... just to provide some more information about how it works for somebody who might come across this

each time the loop runs in the task , one element in `loglist` is provided to the template , so you can access the `item`'s inside the template and loop over the `item.logfiles` (`loglist.*.logfiles`)

Comment: Forgot to say Thanks ! ;)

Comment: @Tomasito the usual way to say thanks on any stackexchange site is to upvote the answer ;)

Comment: @Zeitounator Yep, but it's a pity that 15 points are required to upvote an answer... I'm below that.

Comment: Actually the vote should be recorded but not shown until you get the necessary reputation. You're almost there...